# What should my django serializer def Update look like?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add content for the first time using a **DRF back-end written by someone else**. I am receiving this error...

```
django_1    | AssertionError: The `.update()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
django_1    | Write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer `myapp.tracker.serializers.MedicationSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
```

How can I write the Update method?
I've done rails before so I'm familiar with the concepts? So when I see a method "create" in my serilaizers.py I think "there must be a way to write a def Update here" But since **I'm new to django** I have NO IDEA what that method should actually look like ^_^. This is where I'm stuck.

Here is the serializers.py , models.py, and views.py code specific to the model I am trying to update...let me know if I need to post another files contents.

What should my **def update** method look like?

my serializer.py

```
class MedicationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    cat = CatSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Medication
        fields = (
            'id',
            'cat',
            'name',
            'duration',
            'frequency',
            'dosage_unit',
            'dosage',
            'notes',
            'created',
            'modified',
            'showRow',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        cat_data = validated_data.pop('cat')
        cat_obj = Cat.objects.get(**cat_data)
        medication = Medication.objects.create(cat=cat_obj, **validated_data)
        return medication
```

the models.py looks like this

```
class Medication(models.Model):
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Cat, blank=True, null=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    frequency = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    dosage_unit = models.CharField(max_length=2, default=Weight.MILLILITERS)
    dosage = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    notes = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True, null=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    showRow = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Save time Medication object modified and created times
        self.modified = datetime.datetime.now()
        if not self.created:
            self.created = datetime.datetime.now()

        super(Medication, self).save(*args, **kwargs)



    def __str__(self):
        if self.cat:
            cat_name = self.cat.name
        else:
            cat_name = "NO CAT NAME"
        return "{cat}: {timestamp}".format(cat=self.cat.name, timestamp=self.created)
```

and the views.py ....

```
class MedicationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Medication.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MedicationSerializer
    filter_fields = ('cat__slug', 'cat__name')
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Aliva ... Can you please tell me why I'm getting this error? 

django_1    | AssertionError: The `.update()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
django_1    | Write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer `myapp.tracker.serializers.MedicationSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.

The error seems to be telling me to write an update method. Can you please show me what this should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **read-only=True** to your Catserializer

```
class MedicationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    cat = CatSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Medication
        fields = (
            'id',
            'cat',
            'name',
            'duration',
            'frequency',
            'dosage_unit',
            'dosage',
            'notes',
            'created',
            'modified',
            'showRow',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        cat_data = validated_data.pop('cat')
        cat_obj = Cat.objects.get(**cat_data)
        medication = Medication.objects.create(cat=cat_obj, **validated_data)
        return medication
```

Comment: this worked when I'm updating a record...but now I can't add a new record....so put's now works but it turns off post somehow.